# Prometheus Scrape Configs Label with Slash

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

Trying to filter out some services with a `relabel_config`. On the target I have a label `app.kubernetes.io/name` with a value of `kube-state-metrics`.

When I set up my `relabel-configs` I realized the `.` and the `/` are not valid according to the [Prometheus documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#labelname). I get an error complaining of these invalid characters. Outside of adding a new label on to this service, is this achievable the way it sets? Most Helm charts use this label convention so it would be a lot of work to add additional labels for everything, hoping to avoid it.

```
relabel_configs:
   - source_labels: [app.kubernetes.io/name]
     action: keep
     regex: kube-state-metrics
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prometheus changes dots `.` and slashes `/` to underscores `_` during service discovery, so you need to replace them as well: `app_kubernetes_io_name`. But this isn't the end, you may also need to add `__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_` prefix to it:

```yaml
- job_name: 'pods'
 kubernetes_sd_configs:
 - role: pod
 relabel_configs:
 - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_app_kubernetes_io_name]
   action: keep
   regex: kube-state-metrics
```

Comment: You're correct. I actually figured it out about an hour after I posted it. But thank you for your answer, I will mark it as accepted. Appreciate your contribution.